# Failed to run ruby in emacs shell command on region mode

Tags: emacs, rbenv

I use <kbd>M-|</kbd> to get into shell command on region mode on emacs, 
then just type

```
ruby -e "puts 'ok'"
```

and failed.

The error says ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line4: exec: rbenv: not found.

I use rbenv to setup ruby.

I've add following to my emacs init file,but still not worked.

```
(push "~/.rbenv/shims" exec-path)
(push "~/.rbenv/bin" exec-path)
(push "~/.rbenv/libexec" exec-path)
```

Any help? Thanks.

The line 4 of ~/.rbenv/shims/ruby is

```
exec rbenv exec "${0##*/}" "$@"
```

And command "which rbenv" returns

```
/home/ry/.rbenv/bin/rbenv
```

And command "ll `which rbenv`" returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ry ry 16  2月 29 00:26 /home/ry/.rbenv/bin/rbenv -> ../libexec/rbenv*
```

Comment: What's on line 4 of `~/.rbenv/shims/ruby`?

Comment: exec rbenv exec "${0##*/}" "$@"

Comment: And run which rbenv returns  ** /home/ry/.rbenv/bin/rbenv ** I add it to question

Comment: And if you just type `ruby` from the command line?

Comment: type `ruby -e "puts 'ok'"` outputs ok. so ruby is ok

Comment: Still shooting in the dark: `~/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv` exists?

Comment: it did exists. I check it which ll. And ruby from the command works also means it exists.

Comment: @raykin did you solve this? - what does `echo $path` show? - I've found that `shell-on-command-region` isn't using `exec-path` properly, and am investigating.

Comment: hmmm, don't know why, but it worked now. the difference may be I use emacs24 now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `PATH` and `exec-path` is not configured properly. I wrote up an Emacs package to integrate Emacs with rbenv. This should add the missing configuration: http://blog.senny.ch/blog/2013/02/11/use-the-right-ruby-with-emacs-and-rbenv/